# Another way recharge + Grid + from Jquery + Struts2 jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, grid, reload, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

i have a this code that works good... reload the grid with a click in the button below

```
                <s:url id="remoteurl" action="lisaluXCodYNom" namespace="/"/>
                <sjg:grid
                    id="gridtable"
                    dataType="json"
                    href="%{remoteurl}"
                    pager="true"
                    gridModel="clientes"
                    reloadTopics="reloadMyGrid"
                    rowList="10,15,20"
                    rowNum="5"
                    rownumbers="true"
                    formIds="mcp"
                    onCellSelectTopics="cellselect"
                    >
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="codcli" index="codcli" title="Codigo" sortable="false"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="nomcom" index="nomcom" title="Alumno" sortable="false" width="300"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="facultad.desfacres" index="desfacres" title="Facultad" sortable="false"/>
                    <sjg:gridColumn name="escuela.desesc" index="desesc" title="Escuela" sortable="false"/>
                </sjg:grid>


                <s:form id="mcp" action="lisaluXCodYNom" theme="simple">
                    <s:textfield name="cliente.codcli"/>
                    <s:textfield name="cliente.nomcom"/>
                    <sj:a 
                        button="true" 
                        onClickTopics="reloadMyGrid">
                        Search</sj:a>
                </s:form>
```

now... i want to reload the grid of other way. now i want to reload grid from javascript instead of a button, from here or like this:

```
                $(document).on('change', 'select#combo2' , function() {
                    var valor = $(this).val();

                $.getJSON('lisaluXCodYNom.action?cliente.codcli='+valor, function(datos){
        -- What should I write here to have the same functionality as the button?

                    });
                });
```

Comment: i am try with                         $("#gridtable").trigger("reloadGrid");, but dont work...

Comment: Do you have tried $("#gridtable").publish("reloadGrid"); ?